# My code is exiting with use-after-free error but I don't know why?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm a multithreading beginner and I'm wring the below code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <future>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
 public:
  Foo() {}
  ~Foo() { cout << "foo dtor" << endl; }

  void first(function<void()> printFirst) {
    printFirst();
  }

  void second(function<void()> printSecond) {
    printSecond();
  }

  void third(function<void()> printThird) {
    printThird();
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  thread t1([&foo] {
    function<void()> print11 = [] { cout << "1" << endl; };
    foo.first(print11);
  });
  thread t2([&foo] {
    function<void()> print21 = [] { cout << "2" << endl; };
    foo.second(print21);
  });
  thread t3([&foo] {
    function<void()> print31 = [] { cout << "3" << endl; };
    foo.third(print31);
  });
  sleep(2);
//  t1.join();
//  t2.join();
//  t3.join();
  return 0;
}
```

And I'm getting the error

> "Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

If I uncomment the three `join()` lines, the program exit normally.

I have a feeling that the error is due to use after free, but cannot explain why. What I'm thinking is the main thread will sleep 2 seconds before it really finishes, and during the main thread is sleeping, the t1, t2, t3 should already finish. Hence, even if foo is destroyed, the three thread won't use it after 2 seconds. As far as I understand, it should not have use after free problem. Could anybody explain? Thanks!

Comment: Tip: Stop `using namespace std` and embrace the `std::` prefix.

Comment: Indeed, embrace `std::`  like it's a hot adult film star and not your cousin. Or like it's both if you're from the Southern USA.

Comment: why would you not want to call join?

Comment: If you did know why would you still be asking this question?

Comment: Because I tried and can see `join` can solve the problem (if it's use-after-free issue), but I don't know why not having it will cause an error.

Comment: Sorry I'm only a beginner. I know what `join` means but I just think without `join` we shouldn't have an issue, which is not the case. That's why I'm asking here.

Comment: Without the joins, the object `foo` ceases to exist at the end of `main()` - which means one or more threads can call a member function for it AFTER it is destructed.   That causes undefined behaviour.    Contrary to your claim, there is no guarantee that the thread functions will run to completion before `main()` returns.

Comment: I can see the result of one execution is it actually prints out "123" and then the program exits in error. If it already prints "123", then "foo" is no longer needed, if I understand correctly the three child threads won't call foo's method anymore, why the program still exists in error? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This does not look to me like a use after free problem, and it's not a race condition either. It's required behavior. Attempting to destroy a thread object that is in a joinable state (which yours would be under the circumstances) is *required* to terminate the program (N4835, §[thread.thread.destr]/1):

> ~thread();
>
> 1. If `joinable()`, calls `terminate()`. Otherwise, has no effects. [Note: Either implicitly detaching or
>    joining a `joinable()` thread in its destructor could result in difficult to debug correctness (for detach)
>    or performance (for join) bugs encountered only when an exception is thrown. Thus the programmer
>    must ensure that the destructor is never executed while the thread is still joinable. —end note]

A thread is `joinable()` from the time it starts to run until the time it is `join()`ed or `detach()`ed.

## Summary

Destroying a thread must abort the program if the thread is in a joinable state. To avoid this, join() the thread(s) before destroying them.

Answer (score 2):

The operating system is under no obligation to run your other threads when you `sleep(2)`. It could let Google Chrome have that time slice, or it could use it to do its own background tasks, or it could just sit there on its thumbs.

That logic you just went through of "This thread should only last two seconds at most, so sleeping will do it" is called a *race condition*. You've got two threads and you're making big assumptions about what order things in those threads will happen, without actually enforcing those assumptions. Effectively, your threads enter into a race: if the three child threads win the race, then your program works fine, but if the main thread wins the race, then your program exhibits undefined behavior. And if your program has a chance of exhibiting undefined behavior, then that means that your program's behavior is undefined.

By adding the `join` calls, you enforce your assumption. You demand that the main thread cannot exit until the other three threads finish, which is what you were implicitly assuming before. This makes your program's behavior defined.

Comment: Thanks! I can understand that "The operating system is under no obligation to run your other threads when you sleep(2)", but I'm still confused that I can see the result of one execution is it actually prints out "123" and then the program exits in error. If it already prints "123", then "foo" is no longer needed, why the program still exists in error? Thanks!

Comment: Because undefined behavior is undefined. The compiler is allowed to assume that undefined behavior does not occur, and crucially many optimizations depend on these assumptions. The compiler is making some assumption that, according to the standard, is perfectly valid but which fails in your program. Exactly *what* assumption that is, I don't know. But it's a good enough reason to avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks, thanks! One final question, what does "the main thread wins the race" exactly mean here? From what I learned, when two threads are trying to modify the same memory, it would have a "race condition". Not sure what it means in this particular problem. Thanks!